# Why Does My Samsung Note 4 Shut Off When it Reaches Around 20% Battery Life?

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-note-4

My Samsung Note 4 will work until about 20% battery life.  At that point I usually receive the low battery warning but then it just dies almost immediately after notification with hardly any continued battery drain.   This has been a progressive issue and I believe it is linked to battery health.

I've had it die at even higher battery % at about 30% but that is really rare.

I have owned my Samsung Note 4 for about a year now with the original battery as its only used battery.  I preordered it and received it on release day. The battery has gone through many cycles.  I estimate on average 1 to 2 full drains per day everyday for about a year now.  At this point I tend to just leave it plugged in while I'm near an outlet continuously now.

I charge it with and without the fast charger.  When not in bed I use the fast charger.  When I'm sleeping I use a standard basic charger.

I'm currently using an app called [Battery Monitor Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw&hl=en) to monitor my mAh with this battery.  I also just received a second battery that I will test too.

Does anyone know what could cause my phone to die at around 20%? Is it battery health?

Comment: Battery would be my guess too, fits your description of the problem perfect. Test the second battery for a while - I think it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has responded in the time it took me to do my own little experiment I wanted to post what I found.

I found that I needed a new battery.   The new battery can maintain the needed voltage down to single percentages where as, depending on what I was doing on my phone, the old battery would allow my phone to die with little to no warning like I described in the question above.

So if your phone is not draining much lower than 20-30% and dies try buying a new battery.

Also thank you benjaminS for supporting my thoughts in comments of the question.